# Clearing android overlay when back button is pressed from any app

Tags: android, android-layout

The closest question on SO to this one is this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575537/is-possible-remove-an-overlay-with-windowmanager-when-press-back-or-home-button) but it doesn't answer my question.

I am working on a dictionary application that lets users access word definitions from any app. This works so far as illustrated in the picture below.

[image: Overlay when in app or any other app]

When I click on home however, the overlay is still showing but I do not want this. I want to overlay to be removed when the screen it showed on changed. 
[image: Overlay when not in any app. This is wrong]

I have tried to use TYPE_APPLICATION in the window manager but it doesn't work at all. It says something about can not add token null.

Please check out my windowManager code :

```
DISPLAY_ID = (windowManager as WindowManager).defaultDisplay.displayId
        params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)

        (params as WindowManager.LayoutParams).gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
```

Then I fix it all up here

```
windowManager?.addView(dictionaryView, params)
```

Comment: You do not know when the UI changes underneath you. You will need to add some sort of dismiss option in your floating window (e.g., an X to close it). Also, please make sure that you have adequate documentation showing your license for the Merriam-Webster content and logo, as otherwise your app may be banned from distribution channels (e.g., the Play Store).

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thank you. I would work on that. There should be a way of knowing though. No possible way? Thanks for the merriam webster content tip too. I'd keep that in mind. I wrote about the app when I asked for an api key.

Comment: "No possible way?" -- for privacy and security reasons, Google has been going to *great* lengths to prevent apps from knowing what other apps are doing in the foreground. "I wrote about the app when I asked for an api key" -- OK, just double-check that the terms of service allow you to use their logo. They might offer that, but I have seen too many people get banned from the Play Store because they use other companies' logos, if they cannot demonstrate that they have the rights to use those logos.

Comment: Wow. Thanks @CommonsWare. You should probably write online tutorials if you do not presently. You explain very well and I would look forward to reading your tutorials.

Comment: 6 years after the answer, I reccomend to use the answer field ;)